# Execute script to setup ansible (or another provisioner) for Vagrant?

Tags: shell, vagrant, ansible

The general goal I have is that a member of my team would generally clone a git repo, cd into it, then type `vagrant up`. In particular, I don't want them to have to install anything apart from vagrant and the VM runner (i.e., VirtualBox).

For ansible, I include it in a subtree. It's easy enough to run, e.g., `source ansible/hacking/env-setup`. But, I want this to be as bulletproof and standardized as possible.

Is there a way to get `vagrant up` to run a script like the above to enable the provisioner (on the host)? Or do I need to wrap this in a shell script?

[In case you want a rationale for `vagrant up` over a shell script, Vagrant automatically walks up the source tree to find the appropriate Vagrantfile - so my target developer / designer audience doesn't need to think about where the Vagrantfile is.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alluded to in my comment, for ansible at least, you can solve this via doing shell environment configuration from within the `Vagrant.configure` block. For ansible, the following currently works (assuming you've put ansible in a directory next to your Vagrantfile called ansible):

```
curr_dir = Dir.pwd
ENV['PYTHONPATH'] = "#{curr_dir}/ansible/lib:#{ENV['PYTHONPATH']}"
ENV['PATH'] = "#{curr_dir}/ansible/bin:#{ENV['PATH']}"
ENV['ANSIBLE_LIBRARY'] = "#{curr_dir}/ansible/library"
```

Note that the `ansible/hacking/env-setup` script also sets up the MANPATH. That's obviously of limited utility here!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, I haven't tested this completely as I don't use ansible... but you should get the idea:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    ansible_installed = `ansible-playbook --version` rescue nil
    if !ansible_installed
      `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive; sudo apt-get -y install ansible`
    end
end
```

It will probably ask them for their password as well... but that should be no issue for a one time thing.

Comment: I'll give you a vote up - as I hadn't been thinking I should check if it's installed... I'll also have folks on OS X (and maybe windows), and generally, I want to avoid installing stuff outside the VM. I think I may be able to handle this via just setting shell variables in the ruby script, but I need to make sure they're retained across subshells.